# Weird behaviour of feynmp when using with minipages

Tags: floats, minipage, feynman, feynmp-auto, feynmp

I am using the feynmp-auto with the subcaption package. I have a figure with four identical Feynman diagrams produced with

```latex
\begin{figure}[H] % Do not use only [h] in real documents.
\begin{minipage}[b]{.49\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,60)
    \fmfstraight
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,h,o2}
    % gluons
    \fmf{gluon}{i1,t1}
    \fmf{gluon}{t2,i2}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.5}{t1,o1}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.5}{t2,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    % top loop
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1}{t1,t2,t3,t1}
    % Higgs boson
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2.0}{t3,h}
    % labels
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{X}{h}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\vspace{4ex}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.49\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,60)
    \fmfstraight
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,h,o2}
    % gluons
    \fmf{gluon}{i1,t1}
    \fmf{gluon}{t2,i2}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.5}{t1,o1}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.5}{t2,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    % top loop
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1}{t1,t2,t3,t1}
    % Higgs boson
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2.0}{t3,h}
    % labels
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{X}{h}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\vspace{4ex}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.49\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,60)
    \fmfstraight
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,h,o2}
    % gluons
    \fmf{gluon}{i1,t1}
    \fmf{gluon}{t2,i2}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.5}{t1,o1}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.5}{t2,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    % top loop
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1}{t1,t2,t3,t1}
    % Higgs boson
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2.0}{t3,h}
    % labels
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{X}{h}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\vspace{4ex}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.49\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,60)
    \fmfstraight
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,h,o2}
    % gluons
    \fmf{gluon}{i1,t1}
    \fmf{gluon}{t2,i2}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.5}{t1,o1}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.5}{t2,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    % top loop
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1}{t1,t2,t3,t1}
    % Higgs boson
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2.0}{t3,h}
    % labels
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{X}{h}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}  
\vspace{4ex}
\end{minipage}
\caption{A caption.}
\end{figure}
```

This produces the following (as it should):

[image]

However, now if I add a section with an additional Feynman diagram:

```latex
\subsection{Test}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(140,90)
    \fmfleft{d,i1,d,d,i3,d}
    \fmfright{o1,d,o2,d,o3}
    \fmf{gluon,tension=1.2}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{gluon,tension=1.2}{v3,i3}
    \fmf{fermion}{o1,v1}
    \fmf{fermion}{v3,o3}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.3}{v1,v3}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{fermion}{v1,v2,v3}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=1.3}{v2,o2}
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i3}
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$t$}{o3}
    \fmflabel{$\bar{t}$}{o1}
    \fmflabel{H}{o2}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
```

This suddenly switches the feynman diagram of the first figure with the one on the second figure:

[image]

Why does this happen? Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Did you try using just one `\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}` instead of several, or, if you use several, giving them different names?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Giving them different names did the job, thanks!